# Selecting any two values, and getting all documents associated with those two values

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where there is a field "name". One name can be associated with multiple documents. I need to select any two names, and get all the documents associated with those two names.

This is what I have so far:

```
db.listings.aggregate({$group: {"_id": "$name"}},
{$limit: 2},{$match: {"name":"$_id"}})
```

Here are some example documents:

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "name" : "John", "copies" : 2 },
  { "_id" : 8752, "name" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 },
  { "_id" : 8645, "name" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 },
  { "_id" : 7000, "name" : "Chris", "copies" : 10 },
  { "_id" : 7020, "name" : "Chad", "copies" : 10 }
```

And my results would be something like this:

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "name" : "John", "copies" : 2 },
{ "_id" : 8752, "name" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 },
{ "_id" : 8645, "name" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- `$facet` to separate the result

  - `names`, `$group` by null and get all unique `name` by `$addToSet`
  - `$project` and `$slice` to get latest first 2 `name` from `names` array
  - `all`, to get all root documents
- `$project` and `$filter` to iterate loop of `all` array and filter documents for that sliced first 2 `names`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `all` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `all` object in to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      names: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            names: { $addToSet: "$name" }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            names: { $slice: ["$names", 2] }
          }
        }
      ],
      all: [{ $match: {} }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      all: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$all",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this.name",
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$names.names", 0] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$all" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$all" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lK8wqIGIZkG)